# 'NgModule' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular

I don't know why I'm getting this error in this module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { AdminHeaderComponent } from '../admin/admin-header/admin-header.component';
import { AdminLeftSideComponent } from '../admin/admin-left-side/admin-left-side.component';
import { AdminContentComponent } from '../admin/admin-content/admin-content.component';
import { AdminFooterComponent } from '../admin/admin-footer/admin-footer.component';
import { AdminControlSidebarComponent } from '../admin/admin-control-sidebar/admin-control-sidebar.component';
import { AdminDashboard1Component } from '../admin/admin-dashboard1/admin-dashboard1.component';
import { AdminDashboard2Component } from '../admin/admin-dashboard2/admin-dashboard2.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AdminComponent } from "../admin/admin.component";
import { StarterRoutingModule } from "./starter-routing/starter-routing.module";
import { StarterComponent } from "./starter.component";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StarterRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    AdminHeaderComponent,
    AdminLeftSideComponent,
    AdminContentComponent,
    AdminFooterComponent,
    AdminControlSidebarComponent,
    AdminDashboard1Component,
    AdminDashboard2Component
  ],
  exports: [StarterComponent]
})
export class StarterModule { }
```

I have a pretty identical module and it compiles properly.

This is a very strange behavior... It never happened before.

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace this line :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
```

With :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 2):

Import `NgModule` from `@angular/core` instead of `@angular/compiler/src/core`. The wrong path was given during *auto-import* used by IDE.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```